# Can't find a proper Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle list based on if a link is hovered on.

Here is my jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('.lists li').hover(function(){
        $('ul.list-display', this).toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class='lists'>
    <li><a href='http://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/preview/01_values.html'>Values, Types, and Operators</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='http://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/preview/02_program_structure.html'>Program Structure</a>

        <ul class='list-display'>
            <h6>Test Sections</h6>

            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, it toggles down whenever you hover over the `li` which spans fairly far across the page, so whenever you hover into that `li`, it fires the toggle function.  Ideally I would like the hover to fire when the mouse is over the link with the `ul`, not over the whole area of the `li`.

I think I have to alter my first selector in my function but so far all of my attempts have failed.

Comment: Can't you just add `a` to the selector?

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and it didn't work. I think it has something to do with the a tags being nested in the li.

Comment: Naturally, you'll need to change the way you're targeting the `ul.list-display` since it's a sibling that is next to the `a`, but that's terribly simple. I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: sounds like you want `.lists li > ul`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you used `this` to give a context to the `ul`, but that's why it didn't work when you changed it to trigger off the `a`.  Instead, just traverse the DOM like this:

```
$('.lists li a').hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('ul.list-display').toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Thank you andi, this is very interesting how this works. I'll look at it more, yeah that was exactly what I did initially '.lists li a', I didn't realize the way I was using 'this' would effect how it is selected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('.lists li a').hover(function(){
        $('ul.list-display').toggle('slow');
    }
);

});
```

This appears to be working
http://jsfiddle.net/z6LP5/

Answer (score 0):

It is because your code is working for the list item. Not the hyperlink.

```
$(function(){
    $('.lists li a').hover(function() { // reach the hyperlink
        $('ul.list-display').toggle('slow');
    }
);
```

Now this would execute when you hover over the hyperlink (`a`). And then it would toggle the unordered list with the className of list-display.

Comment: You're toggling all the `ul.list-display` elements. I'm sure that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: The 'this' was for that specific element, with that code above, whenever I hover inside the .lists, everything is being toggled.

Comment: Not all, you should see that there is only **one** list with class list-display :) Other has class for list only...

Comment: Yes, you can now approach for the particular element of hyperlink using `.lists li a` :)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: Come on now. Surely you can see that this is a system of nested menus, so there'll be a separate `ul` for each submenu. The HTML in the question is clearly a minimal example.